# How can UTC be written for following code containing RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.DataSource and RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item:

Tags: c#, sitecore

How can UTC be written for following code containing     RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.DataSource and  RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item:

```
    public ActionResult GetGlobalFooter()
    {
        Sitecore.Diagnostics.Log.Info("GlobalFooter", "DataGoing GlobalFooter");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.DataSource))
        {
            return null;
        }

        var _item = RenderingContext.Current.Rendering.Item;
        var footerItems = this._getGlobalNavService.GetFooterItems(_item);

        FooterModel footer = new FooterModel { NavigationSections = footerItems };
        return View("~/Areas/RemoteOrder/Views/Navigation/GlobalFooter.cshtml", footer);
    }
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.